# Rotation of ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, imageview

I have an ImageView to which I have set an OnTouchListener to enable dragging and rotating it with finger gesture. My problem comes with the rotation, when I do so with my actual code, the result is the Bitmap rotating as expected but overlaying the previous version, as shown in the picture attached. Do anyone has an idea why this is happening? Thanks.

```
//Touch event related variables
int touchState;
final int IDLE = 0;
final int TOUCH = 1;
final int PINCH = 2;
float dist0, distCurrent;
float angle;

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    boolean handledHere = false;

    float distx, disty;

    final int action = event.getAction();

    switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.
        touchState = TOUCH;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        //A non-primary pointer has gone down.
        touchState = PINCH;

        //Get the distance when the second pointer touch
        distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        dist0 = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).

        if(touchState == PINCH){                        
            //Get the current distance
            distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            distCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

            // use angle to rotate view
            angle = getDegreesFromRadians((float) (Math.atan(disty/distx)));
            Log.i("Angle of rotation", angle + "");

            drawMatrix((ImageView) view);

        } else {
            handledHere = startDrag (view);
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //A pressed gesture has finished.
        touchState = IDLE;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        //A non-primary pointer has gone up.
        touchState = TOUCH;
        break;

    }

    return handledHere;
}

    private void drawMatrix(ImageView view){
    float curScale = distCurrent/dist0;

    if (curScale < 0.5){
        curScale = 0.5f;    
    } else if (curScale > 1.5){
        curScale = 1.2f;
    }

    Bitmap originalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //view.getDrawingCache();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    int[] originalSize = (int[]) view.getTag();
    int newHeight = (int) (originalSize[1] * curScale); //(view.getHeight() * curScale);
    int newWidth = (int) (originalSize[0] * curScale); //(view.getWidth() * curScale);

    view.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(originalBitmap, newHeight, newWidth));

}

private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // rotate the bipmap
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

[image: image rotation]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear the canvas before drawing a the rotated image.

I will instantiate the `canvas` in the `constructor` and will apply a `PorterDuff` just before drawing the image

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the ImageView.setScaleType(MATRIX) and play with the Matrix methods.
You could even scale, translate and rotate with the Matrix.